# Bubble sort not working

Tags: java, bubble-sort

```
package package13;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Sorter {

    public static void main (String[] args) {


        int i,j;
        String select;

        int inputArray[]=new int[10];
        System.out.println("Enter 10 numbers:");
        Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);
        for (i=0;i<inputArray.length;i++) {
            inputArray[i]=scan.nextInt();
        }
        for (j=0;j<inputArray.length;j++) {
            System.out.print(" "+inputArray[j]);
        }
        System.out.println("\nHow would you like to sort these numbers?");
        System.out.println("Your choices are: Selection, Insertion, or Bubble");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner (System.in);

        select = scanner.nextLine();
        String choice = select.toString();

        String answer=choice;

        //going to use a switch for this

        choices Choice = choices.valueOf(answer.toUpperCase());

        switch(Choice) {
        case SELECTION:
            System.out.println("Selection sort:");
            int min;

            for (int k=0; k < inputArray.length; k++) {
                min=k;
                for (int l=k +1;l<inputArray.length;l++) {
                    if (inputArray[l] < inputArray[min]) {
                        min=l;
                    }
                }
                if (min != k) {
                    final int temp = inputArray[k];
                    inputArray[k] = inputArray[min];
                    inputArray[min] = temp;
                }
                System.out.println(inputArray[k]);

            }
            break;
        case INSERTION:
            System.out.println("Insertion sort");
            int blue, temp;
            for (int red=1;red<inputArray.length;red++) {
                blue=red;
                temp=inputArray[red];
                while (blue!=0&&inputArray[blue-1]>temp) {
                    inputArray[blue]=inputArray[blue-1];
                    blue--;
                }
                inputArray[blue]=temp;
            }
            for (int green=0;green<inputArray.length;green++) {
                System.out.println(inputArray[green]);
            }
            break;
        case BUBBLE:
            System.out.println("Bubble sort");
            int cat, dog;
            boolean fixed=false;

            while (fixed==false) {
                fixed=true;

                for (dog=0;dog<inputArray.length;dog++) {
                    if (inputArray[dog] > inputArray[dog+1]) {
                        cat = inputArray[dog+1];
                        inputArray[dog+1]=inputArray[dog];
                        inputArray[dog]=cat;
                        fixed=false;
                    }
                }

            }

            for (int mouse=0;mouse<inputArray.length-1;mouse++) {
                System.out.println(inputArray[mouse]);
            }
            break;
        }

    }
    public enum choices {
        SELECTION,
        INSERTION,
        BUBBLE
    }

}
```

Its supposed to ask a user to enter ten numbers using arrays. Then the program asks user which sorting algorithm to be used to sort these numbers. Finally the program prints the array sorted by the algorithm user selected.
I cant find out why the bubble sort isnt working
any help?

Comment: How exactly is it not working?

Answer (score 1):

You need to do nest some loops together. I would say you should write your own code. But who really cares about bubble sort.

---

**Explanation of bubble sort**

Basically, bubble sort works by checking adjacent values(values next to each other) and swapping them depending if the first one is greater. It continually iterates back through the list(array) until everything is in order.

---

**Simple nested loop**

```
for(int i = 0; i < arrayInput.length; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < arrayInput.length-1; j++){
        if(arrayInput[j] > arrayInput[j+1]){
            //swap values
        }
    }
}
```

**Do while**

```
boolean swapped = false;

do{
   swapped = false
   for(int j = 0; j < arrayInput.length-1; j++){
       if(arrayInput[j] > arrayInput[j+1]){
          //swap values
          swapped = true;
       }
   }
}while(swapped);
```

**Recursive** (just made this one up :P)

```
Boolean swapped = true;
while(swapped){
    swapped = bubblehelper(arrayInput);
}

Boolean bubblehelper(int[] arrayInput){
      Boolean swapped = false;
      for(int j = 0; j < arrayInput.length-1; j++){
           if(arrayInput[j] > arrayInput[j+1]){
              //swap values
              swapped = true;
           }
       }
       return swapped;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Bubble sort has 2 loops. You've only got one.

http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithms/Bubble_sort

Answer (score 0):

From Wikipedia.

```
boolean changed = false;
    do {
        changed = false;
        for (int a = 0; a < comparable.length - 1; a++) {
            if (comparable[a].compareTo(comparable[a + 1]) > 0) {
                E tmp = comparable[a];
                comparable[a] = comparable[a + 1];
                comparable[a + 1] = tmp;
                changed = true;
            }
        }
    } while (changed);
```

Your Code.

```
        boolean fixed=false;

        while (fixed==false) {
            fixed=true;

            for (dog=0;dog<inputArray.length;dog++) {
                if (inputArray[dog] > inputArray[dog+1]) {
                    cat = inputArray[dog+1];
                    inputArray[dog+1]=inputArray[dog];
                    inputArray[dog]=cat;
                    fixed=false;
                }
            }

        }
```

Can you see the difference?